# Xamarin how to bind a text color in code only

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Trying to figure out how I can bind a text color to a label. I have done this previously on background colors using `Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty` as my first parameter in the `SetBinding` method, as such:

```
ShowReadOverlay.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, new Xamarin.Forms.Binding("BackgroundColor", Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.Default, new XamarinMobile.Converters.GridCellBackgroundColorConverter(), null, null, null));
```

However, there is no `Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.TextColorProperty` and I do know you can bind a text color in XAML via `<Label TextColor={Binding BindingPropertyName}..` but unsure how to accomplish this in code only.

Here is what I tried, obviously it did not work because there is no `Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.TextColorProperty`:

```
headline.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.TextColorProperty, new Xamarin.Forms.Binding("BackgroundColor", Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.Default, new XamarinMobile.Converters.GridCellBackgroundColorConverter(), null, null, null));
```

Thanks.

Comment: if your element is Label, use Label.TextColorProperty

Comment: @Jason thanks! I think that worked! I'll check your answer if you want to make one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can do something like (for a Label).

you should use

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

myLabel.SetProperty(Label.TextColorProperty, new Binding("BackgroundColor", BindingMode.Default, new GridCellBackgroundColorConverter()));
```